# I want to Create a video Library with a Q&A for each video. How?

Tags: discussion-board, video

I want to create a series of training videos for my organization. And I would like to publish them to our Sharepoint site for easy access.

I know I can create an Asset Library where they can be stored. But what I want is to be able to have one video per page and a Question & Answer discussion below it for just that video.

Is this possible and if so, can you give me some direction on how to accomplish.

I am a relative noob to sharepoint. This site was dropped in my lap one day and was told it is now mine to develop.

Answer (score 0):

First option, is to create a community site in Share Point and link the videos to your asset library by embedding it, this will give you a TRUE Q&A . Second option, depending if you organization is on Office 365, you can utilize Office 365 Video.You can create a channel per training course, in terms of Q&A this would be achieved by Yammer integration. I think this is the best option as Video is optimized for streaming and provides viewer stats.

See https://products.office.com/en-us/business/explore-office-365-video for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a Q&A list, tag Q&A item with specific video. So you can have more flexible with which Q&A goes with which video; one Q&A goes to two videos or vice versa.

Steps:
1. create a Q&A list, add a custom slug column.
2. create a Content Search Web Part in the Video page template, write the query to search and match the URL slug. And only pull back the Q&A that matches the slug. So you just need to drop one CSWP and SharePoint will do the rest for you.
3. Whenever you upload a video, you create a Q&A item in the list, and make sure the slug matches to the video url slug.

Let me know if you have more questions.